# How do I automatically execute war files at Jenkins?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jenkins, war

I am going to use `Jenkins` to execute the project automatically. The project is uploaded to `github` and succeeded in building `War` files using `Jenkins`. `War` file were moved to Tomcat's `Webapps` file, and Tomcat built it, but Tomcat runs properly, but projects don't run the project.

**Setting**

[image]
[image]

[image]

**init_server.sh**

```sh
echo "> Check the currently running spring server pid "
 CURRENT_PID=$(ps -ef | grep java | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$CURRENT_PID" 
 if [ -z $CURRENT_PID ]; then
echo "> No applications are currently running and will not be shut down." 
else
echo "> kill -9 $CURRENT_PID" 
kill -9 $CURRENT_PID
sleep 10
fi
 rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ji**t /usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ji**t .war
 echo nohup mv /root/jenkinsproject/deploy/*.war /usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/jinheeproject.war >> /root/jenkinsproject/logs/springtestprojectSys.log &
  mv /root/jenkinsproject/deploy/*.war /usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ji**t.war
 sleep 10
 cd /usr/local/tomcat9/bin
 ./startup.sh
 echo "Execution complete."
```

[image]

**application.yml**

[image]

Run build in Jenkins, Follow the instructions in the Shell file, turn off the old Tomcat, and run the new Tomcat. And I type 'serverIP:8080' and the Tomcat server starts. But if I type 'serverIP:8080/helloworld', I see 404 error.

> NOTE: I tested my project in the local environment. It was successful.
>
> example: localhost:8080/helloworld

**server.xml in cloud server**

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" >


   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

   <Context path="" docBase="ji**t"  reloadable="false" />
</Host>
```

**my catalina logs**

```
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.226 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.31
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.229 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 5 2020 19:32:12 UTC
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.31.0
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-59-generic
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.231 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04-b08
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.231 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Private Build
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.232 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat9
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.232 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat9
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat9
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat9
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.235 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat9/temp
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.235 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.451 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.498 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [518] milliseconds
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:23.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.202 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.296 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/host-manager]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [31] ms
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/manager]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.352 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/manager] has finished in [24] ms
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.352 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ROOTBEFORE]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/ROOTBEFORE] has finished in [12] ms
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/docs]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat9/webapps/docs] has finished in [14] ms
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.383 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Mar-2020 16:55:27.391 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [3,892] milliseconds
```

Comment: Jenkins is a build server, you don't replace the build server. Instead you run the instance of your new software on different port. On machine where jenkins is installed if you have java setup and tomcat installed copy war to webapp and restart tomcat.

Comment: @silentsudo Isn't my shell file moving warfiles and running Tomcat now?

Comment: Is your .war file deployed. what does server.log says?

Comment: did you add any context path in spring boot application

Comment: @silentsudo How do I add it?

Comment: @silentsudo You can see that the Warfile has been moved by looking at my screenshot picture.

Comment: in your application.properties or application.yml do you something like this `server.contextPath=/server-path`

Comment: @silentsudo  I added the settings, uploaded to the flaghub, tried the build again, but it didn't change.

Comment: @silentsudo I tested this locally, but I'm successful locally.

Comment: when you change you have to access differently `localhost:port:/ji***/` i suspect your application is not running at all, you need to investigate logs, pelase post tomcat server logs to investigate further

Comment: @silentsudo How can I investigate?

Comment: share us logs, `CATALINA_BASE/logs directory`

Comment: there are no panic logs, can you login into tomcat manager console and see the application status?

Comment: @silentsudo I edited the question. Would you look at it? Many settings have been modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something I was missing. I forgot to inherit SpringBootServletInitializer and set it up.

**application.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```